# Excel VBA - Delete the row if values from different tables are equal

Tags: excel, vba

I have an example table that consist as follows

**Worksheet 1**

```
User Name Age
```

**Worksheet 2**

```
User Name Age
```

I want to delete the row from **Worksheet2** if the **User** is the **same** as the **User** on **Worksheet 1**

I've written the following VBA program but I keep getting an **Object Required** error and I have no idea why that is

```
    Sub columnCompare()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, r1 As Range, r2 As Range
  Set sh1 = Worksheets("Users SBC")
  Set sh2 = Worksheets("Users JDF")
  Set r1 = sh1.Range("A2")
  Set r2 = sh2.Range("A2")
  While r1 <> ""
    Set r2 = sh2.Range("A2")
    While r2 <> ""
        Set r2 = r2.Offset(1, 0)
        If r1 = r2 Then r2.EntireRow.Delete
    Wend
    Set r1 = r1.Offset(1, 0)
  Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: When you do `r2.EntireRow.Delete` it will delete the object from `r2` and after the code is confused when `set r2=r2.Offset(1,0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some changes to your code. As I said in my comment, deleting row where you `r2` is will wipe it.

```
Sub columnCompare()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, r1 As Range, r2 As Range, i As Integer
  Set sh1 = Worksheets("XX")
  Set sh2 = Worksheets("YY")
  Set r1 = sh1.Range("A2")
  Set r2 = sh2.Range("A2")
  While r1 <> ""
   Set r2 = sh2.Range("A2")
    While r2 <> ""
        If r1 = r2 Then r2.Value = "delete"
        Set r2 = r2.Offset(1, 0)
    Wend
   Set r1 = r1.Offset(1, 0)
 Wend
 For i = r2.Row To 2 Step -1
    If sh2.Range("A" & i).Value = "delete" Then sh2.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
 Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to first do the offset, and then delete the previous row (with a negative offset). Saves you the For-Loop at the end of the other answer.

```
While r1 <> ""
  Set r2 = sh2.Range("A2")
  While r2 <> ""
    If r1 = r2 Then
      Set r2 = r2.Offset(1, 0)
      r2.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
      Set r2 = r2.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
  Wend
  Set r1 = r1.Offset(1, 0)
Wend
```